# coding a basic math formula

Tags: java

I am trying to write a scanner program to ask the user for the length of a pendulum, L and then find the period of T in seconds. I am basing everything off of the formula below.

T = 2pi*sqrt(L/G)

where I have G as the named constant of 9.8 and L as the pendulum length. 
Here is what I have so far. Can anyone help me out? 
I am basically trying to solve for T when given L, and knowing G is 9.8.

```
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
import java.util.Scanner;
Public class Math
Scanner scan = new scanner(system.in);
System.out.print("Type the length of your pendulum: ");
double pendulum length = keyboard.nextdouble();
final double G = 9.8 meters per second,
             pi = 3.14159;
double powerTerm = Math.pow(pendulumLength, G, pi);
double periodOfpendulum = 2*pi*Math.sqrt(L/G);
System.out.println("The period of the pendulum is " +period+ " per second");
scan.close();

}
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem, exactly?  This code won't even compile.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - You can see that the code snippet above doesn't work.  It's just a rough sketch of how Kyle thinks this should be done.  And he's roughly right - he just needs some help.

Comment: `G = 9.8 meters per second`? I am confused by the `meters per second`.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Eclipse, and so as not to distract, this has been removed from your tags and your question title.

Comment: And you're aware that this formula tells you a number of seconds, not a number of periods per second, right?

Comment: that's it yes. I know this code won't compile and I am currently at a road block with it. Based on the formula in there I want to basically find T, given the length of someone's pendulum.

Comment: Based on your posted code, your best benefit will come from studying an introductory Java text book. Please have a look at the basic structure of a Java class, as it will help you progress faster than any code or advice we can give you here.

Comment: Your code is so scrambled it's hard to know where to begin offering help. I suggest that you start with a simple Java program that compiles (for example, one of the countless "Hello World" programs you can find on the web). Then modify it to do what you want.

Comment: Tip: careful when divide by two variables from user input, handle exception use try catch

Comment: He's not dividing two variables from user input.

Comment: How is "unclear what you're asking" a valid close reason for this?  It's perfectly clear what Kyle is asking.  He's got all the bits he needs in his question; he just doesn't know how to shuffle them round into a working program.  It will be very sad if this gets closed for this reason.

Comment: Since this was inexplicably closed while I was writing my solution, I have had to post my solution at http://pastebin.com/U15Bw2CN - I tried to produce a more object-oriented answer than the other solution here, for those who like that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Math {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Type the length of your pendulum: ");
    double L = scan.nextDouble();
    final double G = 9.8, PI = 3.14159;
    double period = 2*PI*java.lang.Math.sqrt(L/G);
    System.out.println("The period of the pendulum is " +period+ " per second");
    scan.close();

}
}
```

Yours has several issues with it.

```
> {
> public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception { // main() should go after class declaration; why are you throwing an Exception?
> import java.util.Scanner; // import statements go at the very beginning (before class declaration)
> Public class Math // move before the main method
> Scanner scan = new scanner(system.in); // Upcase second scanner (needs to match the type "Scanner"; 'system' -> 'System'
> System.out.print("Type the length of your pendulum: ");
> double pendulum length = keyboard.nextdouble(); // where did you get "keyboard"?. Remove space from variable name
> final double G = 9.8 meters per second,pi = 3.14159; // meters per second doesn't belong; comment it out
> double powerTerm = Math.pow(pendulumLength, G, pi); // what is powerTerm used for? You never call it anywhere
> double periodOfpendulum = 2*pi*Math.sqrt(L/G); // rename class, or use java.lang.Math to disambiguate your class from the java.lang.Math class
> System.out.println("The period of the pendulum is " +period+ " per second"); // be consistent with variable names - periodOfpendulum not period. Not a syntactical issue, but shouldn't it be "period seconds" not "period per second"?
> scan.close();
> 
> } }
```

The main method cannot go before:

```
public class Math
```

Place all your imports at the very beginning.

I would recommend calling your class something other than "Math", since that is already an existing Java library, and when calling methods like Math.pow, you would need to specify java.lang.Math.pow.

Make sure all your variable names are consistent. Also, pay careful attention to capitalization.

A lot of issues with your code. Comment if you need help understanding the code I posted.